# Is it possible to create a composite index using a struct and a field inside another sruct?

Tags: go, go-gorm, composite-index

I was wondering if it would be possible to create an index using a primitive field and the fields of another struct inside a third struct.

I have a YearMonth struct that has some convenient methods I use across my API
I also use this struct to provide the year and month fields for my other structs that need it. and to create this index on other tables as well.

```
type YearMonth struct {
    Year  int        `uri:"year" gorm:"index:,unique,composite:year_month,priority:1" json:"Year"`
    Month time.Month `uri:"month" gorm:"index:,unique,composite:year_month,priority:2" json:"Month"`
}
```

I bumped into a different case where I would need to add another field to complete my unique constraint

```
type CloudfrontData struct {
    YearMonth        `gorm:"index:,unique,composite:year_month_account,priority:1"`
    AWSAccount       string `gorm:"index:,unique,composite:year_month_account,priority:2"`
    BytesTransferred float64
    ModelWithoutID
}
```

Is there a way to create the index **year_month_account** without creating the **year_month** index and by using the **YearMonth** struct?
I would like to keep reusing YearMonth and it's convenient methods without having to replicate them.

Thanks in advance